# Show Bootstrap tab loaded using Ajax doesn't work the first time it's clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to load the content of a given tab using Ajax.

The first tab I render on the server as being active, and the others I active and load using Ajax.

I've isolated the problem (without Ajax) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/om3xsesx/).

HTML:

```
<h1>Hello, tabs!</h1>

<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>

        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>

        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var ref = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');

    var html = '<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="' + ref + '">Brace yourself SW7 is coming. ' + ref + '</div>';

    var tabContent = $('.tab-content');

    if (!tabContent.find('.tab-pane#' + ref).length) {
        tabContent.append(html);
    }

    tabContent.find('.tab-pane#' + ref).tab('show');
});
```

The Home tab is rendered already activated.
Click in the Profile tab for example, it will append the content but won't activate the tab. Now, if you click in the Home tab and in the Profile tab again, it'll work correctly.

I'm doing something wrong or this is an 'expected' behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the content DIVs don't exist the first time you click on a tab, so when the Bootstrap code executes it doesn't find the DIV it needs to activate.  The second time you click, the DIV exists, so Bootstrap finds it.  You can get around this by hiding all of the tab content DIVs at the end of the script, and then showing the one that was specified.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var ref = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
    var tabContent = $('.tab-content');

    if (!$('#' + ref).length) {
        // Execute the AJAX here to get the tab content
        var html = '<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="' + ref + '">Brace yourself SW7 is coming. ' + ref + '</div>';
        tabContent.append(html);
    }

    tabContent.find('.tab-pane').hide();
    tabContent.find('#' + ref).show();
});
```

I believe this could be further optimized, but I'm out of time right now and this works...

Comment: Remember the OP is using ajax, and only wants to make the ajax call on the first click, so this answer might be incomplete for him.

Comment: Good catch @Angela. I'll add the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

What was happening was as you said, the following:

- The ajax request was created, and the click handler for the tab was also fired.
- The handler was executed while there's no target content to be shown but it added the 'active' class to the 'li' element.
- When the ajax request was completed I executed the "tab('show')" code but as the 'li' tab was already activated the event was not handled properly.

The said line is this:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap.js#L2081

Adding removeClass before the execution of the tab show worked:

```
el.parent().removeClass('active');
el.tab('show');
```

Where el is the 'a' element.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me doing: 
`$( document ).ready(function() { $('#myTabContainerID a:first').parent().removeClass('active').tab('show');
});`

Answer (score 0):

I solved just

```
$('#mydivid').addClass('show');
```